# Unlocking account from powershell ISE pre made script

Tags: powershell, variables, account

I was busy making a script where a variable is declared containing the information of the user that you can enter in a prompt. 
I thought of this way when I saw that unlock account can't be done with an e-mail address (Logon name after 2000).
But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the code i am running right now.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
$name = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter your name", "Name", "$env:username")
$Test = Get-ADUser -Filter { EmailAddress -eq $name } | Select SamAccountName
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $Test
```

The error i'm getting is

```
Unlock-ADAccount : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\Users\Admcbl\Documents\Powershell.ps1:5 char:1
+ Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $Test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Activ...ement.ADAccount:ADAccount) [Unlock-ADAccount], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.UnlockADAccount
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What have you tried so far to solve the issue? At a quick glance, it might be because you are missing an `=` sign betweeen `$Test` and `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Also `SamAccountNam` should be `SamAccountName`.

Comment: I that was by sloppy copy and pasting it on here but the error message i receive is what i updated in the post

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the `SamAccountName` property of `$Test`:

```
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $Test.SamAccountName
```

But why not just pipe the account to the `Unlock-ADAccount`? Like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { EmailAddress -eq $name } | Unlock-ADAccount
```

Comment: The second option worked like a charm thanks!
I did not know that was possible is my first script

Answer (score 0):

Here might be a simpler solution for you. Notice I switched the filter so `@domain.com` isn't needed

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$name = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Username "

Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $name} | 
    Unlock-ADAccount
```